# How to rigorously transform a sum of tuples into sum of its components?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, summation, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Consider a function $f(x)$, which maps to real numbers.

Let $x \in \mathcal{S} = \{(0,0),(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$.

**I want to define a quantity $I = \sum_{x \in  \mathcal{S}} f(x)$.**

Now, let $x_1$ be the first coordinate of each tuple $x$, i.e., $x_1 \in  \mathcal{S}_1 = \{0,1\}$, $x_2$ be the second coordinate of each tuple in $x$, i.e., $x_2 \in  \mathcal{S}_2 =  \{0,1\}$.

**Then, I define another quantity $J = \sum_{x_1 \in  \mathcal{S}_1} \sum_{x_2 \in  \mathcal{S}_2} f(x_1,x_2)$.**

Clearly, after we expanding out each sum (or by inspection),  $I = J$.

Is there some way to make this connection more formal?

Meaning, how do we transform (say using a series of operations) $\sum_{x \in  \mathcal{S}} f(x)$  into  $\sum_{x_1 \in  \mathcal{S}_1} \sum_{x_2 \in  \mathcal{S}_2} f(x_1,x_2)$ in a more principled way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true in general that if $S = S_1\times S_2$ is a finite set, then $$\sum_{x\in S} f(x) = \sum_{x_1\in S_1}\sum_{x_2\in S_2} f(x_1, x_2).$$ This can be proven various ways, but if you really want to be thoroughly strict in the proof, induction is probably the way to go.

But less rigorously (but still good enough by most mathematical standards), I would go around proving this by noticing that

$$S = \bigcup_{x_1\in S_1}\{x_1\}\times S_2$$ where the union above is disjoint. In general, if $A=A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n$, and $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, it is true that $$\sum_{x\in A} f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{x\in A_i} f(x).$$

Applying this to $S$, you get

$$\sum_{x\in S} f(x) = \sum_{x_1\in S_1}\left(\sum_{x\in\{x_1\}\times S_2}f(x)\right)$$

which is more or less what you want - the only difference left is notational.